# AutoComplete (username/password) with IE10 and hotmail (outlook.com) doesn't work?

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I can't get AutoComplete (username/password) to work  with Hotmail / Outlook.com ( IE10).
I think this just doesnt work hotmail,
or has somebody ever gotten this to work?

It would be nice if somebody could test this, because i dont think iam the only one where it doesnt work.

Here is a list of what i have already tried:

1. activated all check boxes in IE settings (Content -> AutoComplete)
2. Different Computers
3. Run IE Troubleshooter
4. Reset Internet Explorer
5. Use IE on different User Account

Answer (score 2):

Some websites like outlook.com doesn't allow autocomplete, you can use some program like roboform